# How to fetch a file name automatically in to a data frame instead of manually specifying it

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to automate my spark code in Scala or python and here is what I am trying to do

Format of files in s3 bucket is filename_2016_02_01.csv.gz

From s3 bucket the spark code should be able to pick the file name and create an Dataframe

```
example Dataframe=sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header="true").options(delimiter=",").options(inferSchema="true").load("s3://bucketname/filename_2016-01-29.csv.gz")
```

So every day when I run the job it should be pick that particular days file and create an dataframe instead of me specifying the file name .

Any Idea on how to write code for this condition ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood you correctly, you want the file name change automatically based on that day date.
if that's the case:

here is a Scala solution:
Im using [joda-time](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time) to generate that date.

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.{DateTimeZone, DateTime}
...

val today = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy_MM_dd"))
val fileName = "filename_" + today + ".csv.gz"

...
```

Python solution:

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
file_name = 'filename_' + today + '.csv.gz'
```

Comment: @newSparkbabie, hey, if you found this answer useful please accept it.

Answer (score -1):

```
load("s3://bucketname/{}").format(file_name)
```

Comment: It keeps saying that the input pattern does not match any file in the bucket but when I print the file_name its exactly the Input Pattern s3://bucket/{0} matches 0 filessame.Here is the printed File_name=samplefile_2016_02_04.csv.gz and here is the file name in the bucket  File_name=samplefile_2016_02_04.csv.gz.